# Как передать X-CSRF Token yii2

Tags: angularjs, yii2, csrf, meta

Есть RestApi на yii2, нужно подключить проверку по X-CSRF. Клиент на Angularjs. Нужно что-бы Yii возвращал токен CSRF и я его в куки буду писать и при каждом запросе будет проверка. При обычном приложении Yii2 генерирует CSRF в meta

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="ZlRMX2NORlcEG3kvLSARY0sgOm4ODXM/UA4WEDEGLhMUYRsWJxR/bw==">`

А мне нужно получать его через RestApi, что-бы клиент его в куки записывал. Вопрос как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Yii::$app->response->getHeaders()->set('X-CSRF-TOKEN',Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken());
```